# Why is Haskell so slow compared to C for Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: c, performance, haskell, fibonacci

I am just beginner in Haskell. And I writing a code to display the N numbers in the Fibonacci sequence. Here is my code in Haskell,

```
fib_seq 1 = 1:[]
fib_seq 2 = 1:1:[]
fib_seq n = sum(take 2 (fib_seq (n-1))):fib_seq (n-1)
```

When I run this code for higher numbers like `fib_seq 40` in GHCI, it takes a long time to evaluate it and my computer hangs and I have to interrupt. However, when I write the same exact logic in C, (I just print instead of saving it in the list),

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fib_seq (int n){
    if(n==1)        return 1;
    else if(n==2)   return 1;
    else            return fib_seq(n-1)+fib_seq(n-2);   }


void print_fib(int n){
    if(n==0)    return;
    else        printf("%i ", fib_seq(n));
                print_fib(n-1);     }

int main(int argn, char* argc){
    print_fib(40);
    return 0;     }
```

The code is very fast. Takes about 1 second to run when compiled with GCC. Is Haskell supposed to be this slow than C? I have looked up other answers on the internet and they say something about memoization. I am beginning Haskell and I don't know what that means. What I am saying is that the C code and Haskell code I wrote both do the same exact steps and Haskell is so much slower than C, it hangs my GHCI. A 1-2 seconds difference is something I will never worry about, and if C also had taken the same exact time as Haskell, I would also not worry about. But Haskell crashing and C doing it in 1 seconds is unacceptable.

Comment: Don't use `ghci` for benchmarking: compile with `ghc` optimized and run that program...

Comment: I believe `fib_seq(42)` overflows c integer. You get a fast, wrong value (not to mention **undefined behaviour**) with larger values.

Comment: Furthermore in Haskell you **construct a list**. That is another task than calculating the *i*-th number.

Comment: "[The] C code and Haskell code I wrote both do the same exact steps" -- they don't; for one, as Willem Van Onsem points out, there aren't lists anywhere in your C code. You may find [this question asked yesteday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42754808/2751851) relevant.

Comment: @pmg I not going for 42 fibonacci numbers, I limit myself to 40. So, I don't have the overflow.

Comment: @duplode Aren't they the same, in C I am printing and in Haskell, I am just adding to the end of the list. In Haskell I am not doing recursion twice, (as other people on internet do and hence get directed to memoization) it's just one time recursion and adding to the list, like in C - one time recursion and print.

Also, are you saying that if I used a list in C, C will be as slow as Haskell?

Comment: See also [the section on performance in the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info) which covers everything relevant here.

Comment: @Ayatana I'm not making any claims about C. I just meant to point out that they aren't *literally* the same steps, and that the correspondence between them might not be quite as straightforward as your question suggests. (Cf. Daniel Wagner's answer.)

Comment: @Ayatana: "just adding to the end of the list" may involve quite a bit of memory management.  Doing dynamic memory management in C will slow the C version down a bit.  Maybe not enough to be measurable without a lot of samples, but a bit.  As Daniel Wagner shows, algorithm and tool choice matter a *lot*.

Answer (score 17):

The following program, compiled with `ghc -O2 test.hs`, is +/-2% the speed of the C code you posted, compiled with `gcc -O2 test.c`.

```
fib_seq :: Int -> Int
fib_seq 1 = 1
fib_seq 2 = 1
fib_seq n = fib_seq (n-1) + fib_seq (n-2)

main = mapM_ (print . fib_seq) [40,39..1]
```

Some comments:

1. Unlike you, I implemented the exact same logic. I doubt this is the real difference, though; see the remaining comments for much more likely causes.
2. I specified the same types as C uses for the arithmetic. You didn't, which is likely to run into two problems: using `Integer` instead of `Int` for largenum arithmetic, and having a class-polymorphic type instead of a monomorphic one adding overhead on every function call.
3. I compiled. ghci is built to be interactive as quickly as possible, not to produce quick code.
4. I don't have the right version of llvm installed at the moment, but it will often crunch through heavily-numeric code like this much better than ghc's own codegen. I wouldn't be too surprised if it ended up being faster than gcc.

Of course using one of the many well-known better algorithms for fibonacci is going to trump all this nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Guess what happens if "fib_seq (n-1)" is evaluated twice on each recursion.
And then try this:

```
fib_seq 1 = 1:[]
fib_seq 2 = 1:1:[]
fib_seq n = sum(take 2 f):f
            where f = fib_seq (n-1)
```